# degree of splitting field of palindromic polynomial

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be a palindromic polynomial of even degree 2n.
>
> Let $K$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$. Prove that $[K:\mathbb Q] \leq 2^nn!$.

I know that the palindromic polynomial of even degree 2n has a form $x^nq(x+\frac{1}{x})$ for some $q(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$. Then it must be degree n.

With this fact, how can I solve the problem only with field extension and definition of splitting field?

Comment: Use the same idea as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940360/degree-of-splitting-field-of-pqx

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837850/11619) for this specific case, and Lord Shark's link for a nice generalization.

Comment: Thanks for advice!