# Galois group of $4X^{4m}+X^{4m-2}+X^2+4$ (non-abelian with roots of modulus one)

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

For $m\geq 2$, let $P_m=4X^{4m}+X^{4m-2}+X^2+4$. I have checked that for $1\leq m \leq 10$,

1) $P_m$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$

2) All its roots have modulus $1$

3) Its Galois group has order $4^m(m!)$ (computation made with [online MAGMA calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) )

My questions : does anyone know a proof or counterexample for any of those claims ?

What makes this problem interesting in my view is that (according to MAGMA) the Galois group is non-abelian for $m\geq 2$. So we're not in an entirely cyclotomic context here, contrary to what might be expected from the fact that the roots have modulus $1$.

**Update :** There is a unique polynomial $Q_m$ of degree $m$ such that $P_m(X)=X^{2m}Q_m(X^2+\frac{1}{X^2})$. Some small values of $Q_m$ follow below.
As guessed by in user760780's comment below, the Galois group of $Q_m$ is exactly $S_m$.

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
Q_1(y)  & = & 4y + 2 \\
Q_2(y) & = & 4y^2 + y - 8 \\
Q_3(y) & = & 4y^3 + y^2 - 12y - 2 \\
Q_4(y) & = & 4y^4 + y^3 - 16y^2 - 3y + 8 \\
Q_5(y) & = & 4y^5 + y^4 - 20y^3 - 4y^2 + 20y + 2 \\
Q_6(y) & = & 4y^6 + y^5 - 24y^4 - 5y^3 + 36y^2 + 5y - 8 \\
Q_7(y) & = & 4y^7 + y^6 - 28y^5 - 6y^4 + 56y^3 + 9y^2 - 28y - 2 \\
Q_8(y) & = & 4y^8 + y^7 - 32y^6 - 7y^5 + 80y^4 + 14y^3 - 64y^2 - 7y + 8 \\
Q_{9}(y)  &  = & 4y^9 + y^8 - 36y^7 - 8y^6 + 108y^5 + 20y^4 - 120y^3 - 16y^2 + 36y + 2 \\
Q_{10}(y)  &  = & 4y^{10} + y^9 - 40y^8 - 9y^7 + 140y^6 + 27y^5 - 200y^4 - 30y^3 + 100y^2 + 9y - 8 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Interesting! $P_m(X)$ is even and palindromic. Both facts place constraints on the Galois group. See [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837850/11619). The idea being that the roots form quadruplets $\pm\alpha^{\pm1}$. The Galois group will then permute quadruplets, but if you know the automorphic image of one member of a quad, the others are forced.

Comment: Wonder whether [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2940360/11619) comes in handy?

Comment: Item 2 is easy. Substitute $x=e^{it}$. The equation $P_m(e^{it})=0$ is equivalent to (divide by $X^{2m}$)
$$4\cos(2mt)+\cos([2m-2]t)=0.$$
The first term takes alternating values $+4,-4,\ldots$ at the points $0,\pi/(2m), 2\pi/(2m), \ldots,2\pi$. The second term cannot change the sign at those points because its absolute value is $\le 1$. Therefore $P_m(e^{it})$ has a zero $t$ in each open interval $(k\pi/(2m),[k+1]\pi/(2m))$, $k=0,1,\ldots,4m-1$. That's $4m$ zeros of $P_m(x)$ right there, so that's all.

Comment: There's no reason to expect any relation to cyclotomic polynomials just because the roots all have absolute value one because the polynomial is not monic. Take $\alpha$ to be *any* element of a totally real field $K$. Then all the roots of
$$\prod_{\sigma:K \rightarrow \mathbf{R}} (x^2 - (\alpha/N) x + 1) \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$$
have absolute value $1$ for $N$ large enough, and the splitting field contains the field $K$. The Galois group claim is very close just to saying that $\mathbf{Q}(x^2 + x^{-2})$ has Galois group $S_m$, which is pretty much one would expect at random.

Comment: @user760870 Thanks for the feedback. You've pretty much shredded the glamour and mystery of this problem, now all that's left is the computational details ...

Comment: Yeah. I'm willing to wager that the Galois group ends up being $V_4\wr S_m$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've asked a separate question about your wager : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683952/relating-galois-group-of-evenized-reciprocalized-version-to-original-galois-grou